# XCODE SQLITE3 autoincrement delete and update

Tags: xcode, sqlite, sql-delete

I checked on some online resources about deleting an entry in my SQLITE3 table - I think I did it wrongly because the output doesn't seem right.

Example: ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY is defined. So I have id = 1, 2, 3, 4. after deleting (id = 3), upon new insert, I actually get 1, 2, 4, 5 instead of 1,2,3,4...

Can anyone please shed some light? Below is my code.

p/s: I've tried several methods that's why you could see the commented commands.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        BP * bp = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //[self deleteData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from summary where name is '%s'", [bp.Diastolic UTF8String]]];
//        [self deleteData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from summary where id is '%s'", [bp.IDNumber UTF8String]]];
//        [self deleteData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from summary; delete from '%s' where name = summary",[bp.IDNumber UTF8String]]];
        [self deleteData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from summary; delete from sqlite_sequence where name = summary"]];
        NSLog(@"Name %@ is deleted",bp.IDNumber);
        [entries removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

-(void)deleteData:(NSString *)deleteQuery
{
    char *error;

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [deleteQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Entry deleted");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Entry didn't delete");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with 1,2,4,5? Why do you think you need continuous IDs?

Comment: @CL.Thanks for replying. it's for self-learning, to understand sqlite better.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: @CL.i have actually read that. in the end of the assignment, i need to produce something like this (http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-foreign-keys-example) - table for customer_name, salesperson_name, and invoice_record. however I don't know what would happen if i delete a salesperson (say resigned), how would sqlite handle for customer_name and invoice_record?

Comment: [Foreign keys](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) do not depend on the actual values of IDs.